# How to detect update event in model in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Good day to all
The situation is as follows
In the controller, in the update method, I try to update the object
There is an image in the fields of this object
Wrote a trait to process this field and load an image
In the model itself, I called the update method, which just determines the event of updating the object
The problem lies in the following image in the specified directory is loaded and the entry itself in the database does not change
Here is my code

1. Controller
2. Model
3. Trait

There is extra code in the model

```
public function update(Request $request, MainHeader $mainHeader): RedirectResponse
    {
        $mainHeader->update([
            'language_id' => $request->language_id,
            'brandLogoImage' => $request->file('brandLogoImage'),
            'homeTitle' => $request->homeTitle,
            'ourProjectsTitle' => $request->ourProjectsTitle,
            'contactTitle' => $request->contactTitle,
            'feedbackTitle' => $request->feedbackTitle,
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('admin.header.index')->with('success', 'Данные успешно обновлены');
    }
```

```
public function setBrandLogoImageAttribute($value): string
    {
        return $this->uploadImage('brandLogoImage', $value);
    }

    public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
    {
        $this->uploadImage('brandLogoImage', $attributes['brandLogoImage']);
        $this->setBrandLogoImageAttribute($attributes['brandLogoImage']);
        return parent::update($attributes, $options); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
```

```
protected function uploadImage(string $attr, $value): string
    {
        $uploadDir = public_path('uploads/');
        $imageDir = public_path('uploads/image/');
        if (!file_exists($uploadDir)){
            mkdir($uploadDir);
        }
        if (!file_exists($imageDir)){
            mkdir($imageDir);
        }
        if (!file_exists(public_path("uploads/image/$this->table/"))){
            mkdir(public_path("uploads/image/$this->table/"));
        }
        $imageName = Str::random(12) . '.png';
        Image::make($value)->save(public_path("uploads/image/$this->table/$imageName") , 100);
        return $this->attributes[$attr] = (string) "uploads/image/$this->table/$imageName";
    }
```

Comment: i didnt understand what are you trying to accomplish , why are overriding the update ? , i wrote an answer that explain events , because youare overriding the update to do smlthng before the default one . can you please elaborate your question

Comment: I just try to find another way to inject some business logic

Comment: i dont see why you would iuse the update() like that , you could do it all in the controller before you call the update , still if you want i can show you how to listen properly to the update

Comment: is your purpose to know how to detect update ? or how to upload a file and save its location as a field ?

Answer (score 3):

if you call the update methode in your model then you are overriding the default update() of the model class , its not listening to the event it simply runs your code before parent:: , so you need to make sure that the changes you are making does not get overwitten by the parent call .

regarding your question on how to detect update , if you want to perform anything before update than i advise you to use [eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events) or use [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers) , Observers listen to various events regarding your model like updating or updated .. but i think if its only for updating event than you should use [event using closure](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures)

for example :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::updating(function ($user) {
            // do what you want
        });
    }
}
```

If your pupose

Comment: Looks good 
I will try it
Thanks for help

Comment: you are very welcome @ЕвгенийТимченко . check the links for other methods